# How to link these database items? (ERD)

Tags: sql, database, diagram, erd

just need a bit of help as to how to link a table to my database ERD.

I have two tables, Make and Model that store information about Car Makes (Ford,VW) and Model which stores information of Car Models such as (Focus, Golf).

These are linked together in this diagram, however I also need a showroom table that displays information such as Name of the Car in the format: Make, Model, Price

[screencap of ERD](http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/81/ac/81ac49d42a73905db2f89a313ad47b95.png)

The showroom table needs to get information from the model table, such as Model Name and Price, and also it needs to link through MakeID to get the name of the Make of the car, I just need a bit of help as to what fields to put into the showroom table and how to link it to the rest of the ERD (do I need a table inbetween Model and Showroom?).

Thanks for reading I appreciate any help.

UPDATED ERD Diagram - http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/a9/42/a94263ce9a39d37e30ebfe23cd75b233.png

[picture](http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/a9/42/a94263ce9a39d37e30ebfe23cd75b233.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a very important table here which is `CAR` (or Product). Each product in your database will have ModelID and `CAR.ID`, as you can have many cars of the same model. You can also put some car specific information (as color or configuration ID to that table).

Then your ShowRoom will actually have reference to `Car.ID`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, I think that was the table I am missing :) - this looks a lot better now, http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/f6/dc/f6dc1968c13162e2d2d610e1e791e6ea.png .Do I need to put Name and Price in the showroom table aswell? thanks again

Comment: This is a question needs better understanding of business model. But I would not keep Price in the same place as Stock. Usually you have all price related fields on product itself. In ShowRoom you can have date field - for when car was added/removed and it's location in the ShowRoom, so you could find out whether there is any space for extra cars on any given day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to look at your E/R diagram, but MODEL should be one-to-many with MAKE.

SHOWROOM is an interesting table, because it sounds like it should contain what's currently in stock.  I'd call it INVENTORY.  It would have specific VINs - these are the instances that you can actually buy.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yeah i've got it down as a many to one.. the link is just a picture showing the 3 simple tables I just need to figure out how showroom can get the information from the Model table

Comment: I'd say that you can sell several instances of a given make and model; each one will have its own individual VIN.

Comment: yeah thats what the ID in Showroom is for, I really think I need another table linking Model to Showroom that contains a couple FK's aswell but just can't figure it out...